# Reading from a database and adding that value to a variable

Tags: javascript, mysql

My problem is that I can read from a database, but when I try to add the value to a variable, it won't be saved and uses the original value when it was declarated. My question is that can I use the value from the database outside of the "con.query" and if yes how can I save it

here is the code:

```
con.connect(function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  //ez a resze megnezi hogy hany elem van az adatbazisban
  con.query("SELECT COUNT (id) FROM product", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    else{
    hossz=result
    console.log(result)
    }
    });
    //Ez meg fel kellene hogy toltse a mapot az adatokkal
  con.query("SELECT * FROM product", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    
      for(let i=0;i<2;i++){
        storeItems.set([i,{name:result[i].id,price:result[i].price}])
        console.log(result[i].name)
      }
      storeItems.set(result.id,result.price)
      console.log(result)
    });
  });
console.log(hossz)
console.log([...storeItems.entries()]);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBIdg.png)

Comment: Please post the code here rather than a link to an image.

Comment: oops forgot the code

Comment: I"m not familiar with this functionality, but can you use `hossz`, your result, outside of this block?

Comment: I declarated as  ``` let hossz=0```, and I can use it outside of the block but the value stays 0

Comment: It's not declared that way in this code, but `let` is blocked-scoped, so you likely can't use it outside of its block.